# Use R's file.copy() to copy to a network (shared) drive

Tags: r

I need to be able to copy files from my local drive to a network drive using R. The syntax I'm using is:

```
orig_dir <- "C:/Users/bshelto1/Documents/testtoremove1/pcr"
target_dir <- "//nasgwss0075pn/payment_intergrity/Fraud Business Intelligence/Operations Documents/Tableau Server/Source Data/PCR Dashboards/tableau_data"
file.copy(paste0(orig_dir, "/total_pcr_tins.csv"), target_dir)
```

There is no error message. It just prints "TRUE", like it worked.

When I change the target_dir to another local folder, file.copy() works great. I didn't forsee this being an issue since I can write and download from the network drive in R without any issues.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @AdamBirenbaum No error message. It just prints "TRUE" like it worked.

Comment: This may be obvious but I have to ask, do you have write access to the destination ?  If so, is there another location you can try to write to see if it works elsewhere (e.g. a directory w/o spaces in the name) ?

Comment: if you have a network  drive mapped on your windows machine, shouldn't you use `z:/payment_integrity/...` or whatever? click on the `tableau_data` directory on your win and see its file location

Comment: @steveb Yes, I do have write access to the target directory. I took your suggestion and found a network drive that I also have write access but that doesn't have any spaces in the path name, and it wrote to that network drive. I find it weird that a function like write.csv() wouldn't be affected by the spaces in a pathname but file.copy() is affected by it.

Comment: @rawr the absolute path for that shared drive starts with "nasgwss0075pn" and that is the same pathname that I get with clicking in the address window of the shared drive.

Comment: @BrandonS My thought around the spaces in the name was that there is a possibility they would need a `\` before them. Although unlikely, it is something to eliminate as I have seen this cause issues in other situations when not handled correctly.

Comment: @BrandonS Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: @steveb a) thank you for following up (I was out of town for a couple of days) and b) thank you for the escape character recommendation. I actually just tried using a backslash in front of each space in the path name and it worked!

Comment: @BrandonS Unfortunately the backslash didn't show up in my comment; the comment was done from the phone app so I didn't notice this issue until recently.  I am glad it worked and it seems, according to what you said, that both `file.copy` and `write.csv` handle spaces in names differently.  Perhaps you should put the solution in as an answer.